# How can I replace percent sign (%) with two %'s?

Tags: c++

I want to try replace a percentage sign in a char array with two `%%` signs. Because a `%` sign causes problems, if I write as output char array. Therefore percentage sign must be replaced with two `%%` signs without using string.

```
// This array causes dump because of '%'
char input[] = "This is a Text with % Charakter";
//Therefore Percent Sign(%) must be replaced with two %%.
```

Comment: What is the output you want to see?

Comment: How are you using this string - it should work just fine in most places, but if you pass it to for example `printf(input);` then it may cause problems.

Comment: If your trouble comes from what MatsPetersson says, simply do `prinf("%s", input)` (which is the correct way to do it) and be done with it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to handle the necessary memory re-allocations for you, plus a `boost` algorithm to make everything easier:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::string input("This is a Text with % Charakter and another % Charakter");
  boost::replace_all(input, "%", "%%");
  std::cout << input << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> This is a Text with %% Charakter and another %% Charakter

If you can't use `boost`, you can write your own version of `replace_all` using [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace):

```
template <typename C>
void replace_all(std::basic_string<C>& in, 
                 const C* old_cstring, 
                 const C* new_cstring)
{
  std::basic_string<C> old_string(old_cstring);
  std::basic_string<C> new_string(new_cstring);
  typename std::basic_string<C>::size_type pos = 0;
  while((pos = in.find(old_string, pos)) != std::basic_string<C>::npos)
  {
     in.replace(pos, old_string.size(), new_string);
     pos += new_string.size();
  }
}
```